# import IPath in Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was looking now for hours in Eclipse and Internet to find a solution on how to include IPATH in my class in Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0). I don't have any plugin called org.eclipse.core.runtime, which should include the IPath. Is IPath  outdated or do I have to download another plugin?

I only do have org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.11.0.v20150405-1723.jar and org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_3.2.300.v20150423-0821.jar.

Here is a code snippet for what I would use IPath:

```java
IPath path = new Path(" /DirectoryReader.java");
IFile sampleFile =  ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path);
```

Thx in advance, for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

`org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.11.0.v20150405-1723.jar` is the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plugin. The part following the `_` is the plugin version (3.11.0 build v20150405-1723)

To include this as a dependency of your plugin open the 'plugin.xml'/'MANIFEST.MF' editor and go to the 'Dependencies' tab. In the 'Required Plug-ins' section click Add... and select 'org.eclipse.core.runtime' from the list.

Something like:
[image]

Note: When you create a plugin 'org.eclipse.core.runtime' is usually automatically added to the plugin dependencies so you may find it is already on the list.

Comment: That's what I did but when I include it I don't have any IPath nor Path in org.eclipse.core.runtime?

Comment: Those classes are actually in 'org.eclipse.equinox.common' but adding the 'org.eclipse.core.runtime' dependency should automatically include the other plugin.

Comment: On the Overview tab of the plugin.xml editor click the 'Update the classpath settings' to make sure the plugin classpath is set correctly.

Comment: Well, maybe I am doing it wrong and that's why I can't include this. In the project folder I right click my project and under Properties->Java Build Path->Add external Jar, I add the org.eclipse.core.runtime. I am wrong by doing so? I mean the only thing that I wanna achieve is to use an IPath in my code.

Comment: That is wrong. You must use the plugin.xml/manifest.mf editor - and your code must be an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Okay, that 's why! Thx, greg!